# Select a specific part of the output and use it to rename files

Tags: linux, microsoft-excel, unix, terminal, filenames

I'm currently sorting files I recovered from a broken filesystem. They now all have filenames that go something like this: f123123123.xls

If I run: file "f123123123.xls" it gives me a lot of information and sometimes even a last saved date.

Example:

> ./recup_dir.89/f111841280.xls: Composite Document File V2 Document, Little Endian, Os: Windows, Version 1.0, Code page: -535, Revision Number: 5, Total Editing Time: 09:58:37, Last Printed: Wed Sep  9 11:57:04 2015, Create Time/Date: Thu Sep  3 03:15:36 2015, Last Saved Time/Date: Mon Oct 19 14:28:03 2015

How can I select the last saved date and use it to rename my file to something like: Oct-19-2015.xls ?

Answer (score 0):

We can string a few commands together to do it.  I'm going to have this example write the renamed files to another directory, they can be moved where you like, but I personally like to keep them separate in case I have a few false starts.

```
mkdir renamed
for recovered in recup_dir.89/*xls; do
    new_name=$(date +'%b-%d-%Y' -d "$(file "$recovered"| grep -Po 'Last Saved Time/Date:\K[^,]*')")
    if [ -n "$new_name" ]; then
        mv "$recovered" "renamed/$new_name.xls"
    fi
done
```

this will loop over all the xls files in the directory (since this information won't be in the output of all files).  For each one it will run the `file` command and use GNU grep's perl style regex to find where `Last Saved Time/Date:` appears then get just the time after that.  We'll then use the `date` command to reformat that time just how you want, so we don't have to do much manipulation of individual fields in the output.

That will give us a date of the format `Oct-19-2015` and we then use that value in the `mv` command, as you'd expect, but only if we actually got a date back.  If didn't get something back, don't try to rename the file (just in case things don't always work out the right way with the previous chain of commands).